# How to detect movements of objects on iPhone by blowing air?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, ios

I was just finding something on web I come to know that we can provide movements to different objects by blowing air on iphone from mouth.

I tried but could not get how to do such things. so do any one know that how to move objects by blowing air from mouth.

If any one do have any idea please tell me.

If I am now wrong then, 
I must tell, by blowing air nothing is happening. what it's actual logit that I come to know is we are blowing on the microphone of the iPhone. That will generate some noise and using the noise frequency we can generate some actions on iPhone.

If I am wrong then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to download the ESP SDK. I believe if you buy it now, you get a free telekinesis hat

Comment: @Andrew Bullock: I have got it, it's great.  In fact, it was delivered before I had even placed my order.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795968/detecting-blowing-on-the-iphone-microphone/23752651#23752651).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is by recording sound that the phone can hear, and measuring the gain. Low gain implies a small breeze, while the higher the gain would imply more breeze. However, all this breaks down in a noisy environment.

Comment: No i dont' want to record the sounds, but I want to blow air from the end of iPhone and push object to the top of the screen. Is it possible????

Comment: As per jer, Recording is the right choice for your requirement but you can achieve this without recording the sound.No need to record the sound file.

Comment: yes just blow air on the microphone of the iphone and perform the action as we are needed.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean recording the sounds even though I see that's what I typed out. Should have reworded that a little. My apologies.